# Add box shadow to upper 50% of a div

Tags: html, css

I want to apply the box shadow to the ***upper*** half (upper 50%) of the div. I have tried everything but failed.

```
    div{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: gray;
        margin: auto;
        font-size: 30px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    }
```

Like mentioned: I want to add the box shadow to just the ***upper*** half of the div.

```
<div>Some text.</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use pseudo-element to add `box-shadow` and make that pseudo-element `50%` of height of parent div. Also you need to set `z-index: -1` so that pseudo-element appears under `div`.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: relative;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>Some text.</div>
```

Comment: Hello, this seems to work. Thank you.
It looks like there is a problem with z-index for me, though. The pseudo-element (position absolute, z-index -1) is being placed above the original div (position relative, z-index 11). Trying to figure that out now.

Comment: Post a https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/ with your code.

Comment: It looks something like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/scxswyns/

Comment: I fixed it by removing the z-index of the original div! Ty.

Comment: Yes one option is to remove z-index from parent but if you can't do that you can create one wrapper div and set z-index on that element and then you also need to set smaller z-index on `main` div and create stacking context... https://jsfiddle.net/scxswyns/2/

Answer (score 0):

```css
div{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: gray;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 30px;
    border: none;
    border-style: outset;
    border-width: 5px 5px 0 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-color: #6f6f6f;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-right-color: #0e0e0e;
    box-shadow: inset -2px -14px 47px 1px rgba(56,12,12,0.3);
}
```

```html
<div>Box</div>
```

Try this.

```
 border: none;
 border-style: outset;
 border-width: 5px 5px 0 0;
 border-top-left-radius: 5px;
 border-top-color: #6f6f6f;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
 border-right-color: #0e0e0e;
 box-shadow: inset -2px -14px 47px 1px rgba(56,12,12,0.3);
```